# Make AS3 function run every where in timeline? Each 60 second

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can I somehow make a function which runs in all timelines and everywhere?

Which runs each 60 second?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Need more detail

Answer (score 2):

Use [`flash.utils.setInterval`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setInterval%28%29) function:

```
setInterval(functionToCall , 60000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to run a function every 60 seconds and track whenever that function is called from anywhere in the project?

For this you could simply dispatch an event from the root of the project (MainTimeline for example):

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(60000);

timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, handleMinuteElapsed);

function handleMinuteElapsed(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    // Create and dispatch a custom event.
    // You should consider extending the Event class and using your Event instead,
    // this is primarily for demonstration and ease of implementation.
    var event:Event = new Event("MinuteElapsed");
    dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

And now from anywhere in the project in any timeline, you can use this:

```
root.addEventListener("MinuteElapsed", handler);

function handler(e:Event):void
{
    // Do something in response to the event being triggered.
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the very root scene, make a new layer and add the function. Call it from whereever using MovieClip(root).functionName();

Comment: It does depend on what the function does though, what actions does it perform?